# i need to use string variable in the Proc in sql server database 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have this procedure

```
CREATE Proc  [dbo].Salse_Ditail  
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here 
    @Report_Form  varchar(1)  , 
    @DateFrom datetime  , 
    @DateTo  datetime   , 
    @COMPANYID varchar(3), 
    @All varchar(1) , 
    @All1 varchar(1)    ,  
    @All2 varchar(1)   ,  
    @All3 varchar(1)   , 
    @All4 varchar(1)  ,  
    @All5 varchar(1)   ,   
    @Sector varchar(10), 
    @Report_Parameter nvarchar(max)   
as 
BEGIN 
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from 
    -- interfering with SELECT statements. 
    DECLARE @STRWhere nvarchar(max) 

    IF @All5=0 AND @All4=0 AND @All3=0 AND @All2=0 AND @All1=0 and @All=1 
        set @STRWhere=  N'and  Sector_id = @Sector'  

    if @Report_Form =1 or @Report_Form =3 or @Report_Form =4  

    SELECT   RETURNREASONCODEID, SITE,SITE_NAME,Factory_id,Factory_Name,Sector_id,sector_name,Customer_name, 
         Customer_id,ITEMID,ITEMNAME,SALESMANID,SALESMAN_NAME,Net_Qty,Net_Salse,Gross_Sales,Gross_Qty, 
         NETWEIGHT_Gross,NETWEIGHT_salse_Gross,NETWEIGHT_NET,NETWEIGHT_salse_NET,Return_Sales,Free_Good, 
         CollectionAmount   

    FROM hal_bas_new_rep  

    WHERE   DATAAREAID =@COMPANYID AND INVOICEDATE >= @DateFrom  
        AND INVOICEDATE <= @DateTo and Report_Activti = @Report_Form  

    if  @Report_Form =2   

        SELECT   RETURNREASONCODEID ,  RETURNREASONDESC,  SITE , SITE_NAME , Factory_id , 
            Factory_Name ,  Sector_id ,  sector_name ,  Customer_name ,  Customer_id ,  
            ITEMID , ITEMNAME , SALESMANID , SALESMAN_NAME ,    Return_Sales    

        FROM dbo.hal_bas_new_rep  

        WHERE  DATAAREAID =@COMPANYID AND INVOICEDATE >= @DateFrom  
            AND INVOICEDATE <= @DateTo and Report_Activti =   @Report_Form  
            and  RETURNREASONCODEID in 
            ( 
                SELECT     Val  
                FROM dbo.fn_String_To_Table(@Report_Parameter,',',1) 
            )   
            /* 
            @STRWhere   // question: how can I use the variable here?
            */ 
end 
GO
```

As you see I'm constructing a condition for the WHERE clause in a variable, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Please rewrite your question, I can't understand what you are asking.

Comment: What is "but the virble"? Does it mean "put the variable"? What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are doing will work.  What you need to do is turn the statement that constructs the variable into an appropriate condition and add that to your WHERE clause.

```
SELECT   RETURNREASONCODEID ,  RETURNREASONDESC,  SITE , SITE_NAME , Factory_id , 
        Factory_Name ,  Sector_id ,  sector_name ,  Customer_name ,  Customer_id ,  
        ITEMID , ITEMNAME , SALESMANID , SALESMAN_NAME ,    Return_Sales    

FROM dbo.hal_bas_new_rep  

WHERE  DATAAREAID =@COMPANYID AND INVOICEDATE >= @DateFrom  
    AND INVOICEDATE <= @DateTo and Report_Activti =   @Report_Form  
    AND  RETURNREASONCODEID in 
        ( 
            SELECT     Val  
            FROM dbo.fn_String_To_Table(@Report_Parameter,',',1) 
        )   
    AND (NOT(@All5=0 AND @All4=0 AND @All3=0 AND @All2=0 AND @All1=0 AND @All=1)
         OR Sector_id = @Sector)
```

Comment: I can not I can deliver the correct information
but I do wool clarification and explanation
i have report in ssrs  and have many filter if i get this proc it help me to make the report easy and not write the same selection 
many time i use this function but i need in sql 2005 not in other prog 
why ineed to use this sting variable becuse i have many filter 
IF @All5=0 AND @All4=0 AND @All3=0  and others many variable when u use this string variable help u
  i thinks here u can not use the execut under the where or u need to make many proc and write the same selection

Answer (score 0):

You can build all your query in the variable and use EXECUTE to get the result.
Is orrible but work